# How can I get Hibernate to ONLY use Oracle Sequence

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I really hope someone can help!

I have successfully used a Spring/Hibernate web-based application (Tomcat 6x) to insert records into an Oracle database. The Oracle database table that I am writing records to is fairly straightforward - but it is important to know that the first column of the table needs to be populated with the value supplied by a dedicated Oracle Sequence.

The problem that I am having is that when I insert a row, I DO NOT ALWAYS seem to get the value of the Oracle Sequence.

Here is some code, which illustrates the steps I have taken to try to resolve this issue myself:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MARTINI_STORE.STY_ORDER_RETRY_PAYMENT")
public class STYOrderRetryPayment implements Serializable {
/**
 * Serializable class - generated UID
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 4396053457149921483L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="audit_seq")
@GenericGenerator(  name = "audit_seq", strategy = "sequence", parameters = {  @Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "MARTINI_STORE.STY_SOR_ID_SEQUENCE") }
)
@Column(name="SOR_ID", nullable=false)
private long sorId;
```

The code above shows a snippet from the bean I use to persist data to the table. The field, sorId, is mapped to the column on the database table that should be populated with the value supplied by the dedicated Oracle Sequence.

I have tried searching for answers to this issue, but nothing I have tried seems to work...